# Android Event bus passing data from activity to tab fragment

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-fragments

i have 5 tab fragment in my programme, i want to passing data from my toolbar button to 5 tab fragment , but the problem is when i click on my toolbar button it only passing to 3 fragment , anyone have idea to solve this

**Main Activity**

this is my onclick function in MainActivity

```
    public void editpage( View view) {

    ToggleButton etMessage = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    Events.ActivityFragmentMessage activityFragmentMessageEvent = new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText()));
    Events.ActivityFragmentMessage2 activityFragmentMessageEvent2 = new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage2(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText()));
    Events.ActivityFragmentMessage3 activityFragmentMessageEvent3 = new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage3(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText()));
    Events.ActivityFragmentMessage4 activityFragmentMessageEvent4 = new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage4(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText()));
    Events.ActivityFragmentMessage5 activityFragmentMessageEvent5 = new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage5(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText()));
    GlobalBus.getBus().post(activityFragmentMessageEvent);
    GlobalBus.getBus().post(activityFragmentMessageEvent2);
    GlobalBus.getBus().post(activityFragmentMessageEvent3);
    GlobalBus.getBus().post(activityFragmentMessageEvent4);
    GlobalBus.getBus().post(activityFragmentMessageEvent5);

}
```

**list_fragment2**

this is how i recieve data once the toggle button clicked on MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GlobalBus.getBus().register(this);
}
@Subscribe
public void getMessage(Events.ActivityFragmentMessage activityFragmentMessage) {

    messageView2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sum2);
    messageView2.setText(String.valueOf(activityFragmentMessage.getMessage()));
    messageView2.setText(activityFragmentMessage.getMessage());
    i = messageView2.getText().toString();
    result = Integer.parseInt(i);
    if (result == 1) {
        Nsum[0]++;
        editor.putInt(PREFS_KEY,Nsum[0]);
        editor.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(list_fragment2.this).attach(list_fragment2.this).commit();

    }else if (result ==0){
        editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
        editor.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(list_fragment2.this).attach(list_fragment2.this).commit();
    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    GlobalBus.getBus().unregister(this);
}
```

**orderlist_fragment**

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GlobalBus.getBus().register(this);
}
@Subscribe
public void getMessage3(Events.ActivityFragmentMessage3 activityFragmentMessage3) {

    messageView3 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sum3);
    messageView3.setText(String.valueOf(activityFragmentMessage3.getMessage3()));
    messageView3.setText(activityFragmentMessage3.getMessage3());
    i = messageView3.getText().toString();
    result = Integer.parseInt(i);
    if (result == 1) {
        Nsum[0]++;
        editor.putInt(PREFS_KEY,Nsum[0]);
        editor.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(orderlist_fragment.this).attach(orderlist_fragment.this).commit();

    }else if (result ==0){
        editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
        editor.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(orderlist_fragment.this).attach(orderlist_fragment.this).commit();
    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    GlobalBus.getBus().unregister(this);
}
```

**Tab4_fragment**

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GlobalBus.getBus().register(this);
}
@Subscribe
public void getMessage(Events.ActivityFragmentMessage4 activityFragmentMessage4) {

    messageView4 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sum4);
    messageView4.setText(String.valueOf(activityFragmentMessage4.getMessage4()));
    messageView4.setText(activityFragmentMessage4.getMessage4());
    i = messageView4.getText().toString();

    result = Integer.parseInt(i);
    if (result == 1) {
        Nsum[0]++;
        editor.putInt(PREFS_KEY,Nsum[0]);
        editor.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(Tab4_fragment.this).attach(Tab4_fragment.this).commit();

    }else if (result ==0){
        editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
        editor.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(Tab4_fragment.this).attach(Tab4_fragment.this).commit();
    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    GlobalBus.getBus().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: If you're using a `TabLayout` it only inflates a couple of fragments at first, in this case 3 I guess. Your other fragments are not initialized yet.So you will have to check for the data when they are created.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake thanks, did you means that the problem is in my tablayout?

Comment: I mean it's the way you think it works. When you use a `TabLayout` it doesn't inflate all the fragments. This is actually the intended way.

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much i know where is the problem already

Comment: one quick guess would be , check if you add this function in your viewpager **viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit** . If you hvn't set it yet, set it to 5

Comment: yes, it work, what does setOffscreenPageLimit  means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because fragments 4 and 5 are not yet created. add **setOffscreenPageLimit(5)** into viewPager instance. It will keep all 5 fragments into memory instead of using lazy-loading mechanisms.

official docs link [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Comment: thanks again , i am still new in android, thanks for answer my question :)