# Android: how to disable swiping between tablayout control by button click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

i have 2 fragment in my tab layout, i manage to disable the swiping function between tab layout by button click. How to implement the disable function in my onclick button. thanks for advance

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{


private TabLayout tabLayout;

private ViewPager viewPager;
int ans =2;

 ------FCViewPager disable;------

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    BasePagerAdapter adapter = new BasePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
    Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();


    adapter.addFragment(tab1, "1");
    adapter.addFragment(tab2, "2");

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

----- public void testing( View view) {

```
        disable.setEnableSwipe(false);

}---------
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
public class BasePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public BasePagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }


    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Tab1

```
 public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    return  h;
}
```

}

Tab2

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        return h;
    }
```

Comment: This is a java code and you should not tag it as javascript

Comment: what disable function u like to implement ?

Comment: @Sanny  disable swiping between tab, control by button onclick

Comment: similar issue is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442216/how-to-disable-or-enable-viewpager-swiping-in-android

Comment: How do you disable the swipe functionality? I want to only change fragment only on tab click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable swipe feature in your ViewPager. Create custom ViewPager as follow.

```
public class FCViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enableSwipe;

    public FCViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FCViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        enableSwipe = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return enableSwipe && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return enableSwipe && super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

    public void setEnableSwipe(boolean enableSwipe) {
        this.enableSwipe = enableSwipe;
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity

```
//R.id.pager has to be FCViewPager not default ViewPager
viewPager = (FCViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Your button onClick function

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pager.setEnableSwipe(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: in my onclick function i call the method like this  ----public void testing( View view) {
        disable.setEnableSwipe(false);

    }----

Comment: i declare like this----- FCViewPager disable; -----but it dosen't work

Comment: how about just return false in 
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { }

Comment: i modified my code in Main Acitivity can u help me to check it is the right way to implement this method?

Comment: there is another error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.FCViewPager

Comment: Change **<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager** to **FCViewPager** in **activity_main.xml** file

Comment: if i change to FCViewPager java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.FCViewPager" on path:  this error will come out

Comment: it has to be under your package name , not insdie ** android.view **

Comment: That's grt8. Happy coding bro :D

Comment: actually i have another question , did you familiar with the event bus?

Comment: post it on separate thread, i have been working with EventBus :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151055/android-event-bus-passing-data-from-activity-to-tab-fragment, this, i face this problem

Answer (score 1):

User scroll disable viewpager for disabling and enabling scrolling by default and programmatically

```
public class ScrollDisabledViewpager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean isPagingEnabled = false;

    public ScrollDisabledViewpager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollDisabledViewpager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

Button `onClick` event you can set this true/false to enable/ disable scrolling

`viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true/ false);`

Comment: it come out with this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.ScrollDisabledViewpager.setPagingEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                      at net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.Tab1$1.onClick(Tab1.java:55)

Comment: java: 55 =  disable.setPagingEnabled(false);

Comment: this is my declaration ScrollDisabledViewpager disable;

Comment: did you initialize `viewpager` before accessing it null pointer happens for not initialized

Comment: how to initialize my viewpager?

Comment: ScrollDisabledViewpager  pager =  (ScrollDisabledViewpager ) findViewById(R.id.pager);

Comment: there is the error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.ScrollDisabledViewpager

Comment: after i initialize my viewpager